# How to plot sublots when creating plots in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I'm new to programming and currently stuck on this: I create 4 different plots using a for loop and I want to assign each plot to a different subplot. Basically, I want 4 plots in a 2x2 grid so I can compare my data. Anyone knows how I can achieve this? My approach was to create a list of subplots and then assign every plot to a subplot using a nested plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def load_file(filename):
    return np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True, skiprows=1)


fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)

ax_list=[ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]

for i,filename in enumerate(file_list):
    for p in ax_list:
        x,y = load_file(filename)
        plt.plot(x,y,
        label=l, #I assign labels from a list beforehand, as well as colors
        color=c,
        linewidth=0.5,
        ls='-',
               )
        p.plot()
```

The problem is, all plots are assigned to only one subplot and I don't know how to correct this. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Use `p.plot` instead of `plt.plot`.

Comment: What is your `file_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop over filenames and plots, only need to select the next plot in the list.

```
for i, filename in enumerate(file_list):
    p = ax_list[i]:
    x,y = load_file(filename)
    p.plot(x, y,
        label=l, #I assign labels from a list beforehand, as well as colors
        color=c,
        linewidth=0.5,
        ls='-')

plt.plot()
```

You can also replace

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)

ax_list=[ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
```

with just

```
fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax_list = ax_list.flatten()
```

To get a simple 2x2 grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know how to iterate through a list the way you did. This worked out just the way I wanted it to! But I wanted to ask, which part exactly would you replace with
    fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(2, 2)
?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show what I mean to replace, and added in the `flatten()` I was missing, as prompted by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's answer - `subplots` returns a 2d array and flatten just gives you a 1d list.

Comment: how would you add legends here in the first example ?

Comment: @MadhurYadav Just do `p.legend()` within the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to show different data on all 4 plots, hence use a single loop. Make sure to use the axes plotting method, not `plt.plot` as the latter would always plot in the last subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def load_file(filename):
    return np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True, skiprows=1)

fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(2,2)

for i,(filename,ax) in enumerate(zip(file_list, ax_list.flatten())):
    x,y = load_file(filename)
    ax.plot(x,y, linewidth=0.5,ls='-' )
plt.show()
```